# Cannot play more that 30 seconds of music using Deezer SDK with Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sdk, ionic3, deezer

I want to develop a musical mobile app using the Javascript Deezer SDK (I have a premium account).
So far I just made a simple sample with a login button and a play button, calling the DZ.player.playTracks function.
When ran on my browser, it works fine. I log in to my account, the track starts **from the beginning**, and I can listen to it until the end.

The problem is that when I run it on my phone (iOS). At the moment I have an emulator problem, so I connect to the Ionic Server directly with my iPhone. I manage to log in, but even after that, the song starts in the middle of it, and **doesn't last more than 30 seconds**.

I wonder, is it because of Cordova ? Or because of Deezer ? I'm sure it is possible to play a sound more than 30 seconds via a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the sad answer: Impossible to play more than 30 seconds extracts on mobile using Javascript SDK. See answer on Deezer website https://developers.deezer.com/musicplugins/player

--> "Due to Flash restrictions on mobile, only 30 seconds previews can be provided."